# ubuntu 14.04 : can't move chrome window

Tags: 14.04, gnome, google-chrome, window, resize

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, and installed Google Chrome.

My problem comes from the fact that I can't move the chrome window on my second screen or even on the "current" screen. I'm also not able to resize it.

You can see google chrome opened in the following screenshot and it just stay like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCDtx.jpg
The only thing I can do is minimize it.

I think there's something wrong as the gnome toolbar is not visible : it should be over the top of the chrome window. When I open an other program, gnome toolbar is visible and window is resizable and movable where I want.

When I click on the chrome window and try to drag it, it seems like it does not see that I try to drag it.

I'm aware that I didn't give a lot of technical information but this is all I have as it seems like an unusual problem.

Chrome version is 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit) and I use Gnome with no effects.

Can somebody help me ? Did anybody already had the problem ?

Comment: Right click on the blue area at the right of the tab and select "Use system title bar and borders" and see if that still happens. Also try to install Chromium to see if it has the same problems (`sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`).

Comment: Well, after a few minutes where everything works well, the same symptom appears on chromium. It just closed with no reason and when I restarted it, it was stick to the top of the window, as chrome was. Now, I can't move anymore the chromium window. So problem is not solved, not even bypassed...

Comment: Try to start it from a terminal using `chromium-browser --blacklist-accelerated-compositing`

Comment: It does not change anything and moreover, now, chromium close as soon as I try to do a search in the toolbar or directly on the google.fr page... It is just driving me crazy now !

Comment: Thanks @Salem "Use system title bar and borders", worked for me

Comment: I was having the same problem (but with Ubuntu 12.04), and found that enabling "Use system title bar and borders" and then restarting the browser worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue where I was not able to resize or move my chrome window to the 2nd screen.

What I did is this :
Left click and hold an open tab in google chrome window (Not the blue area, click in the white area inside one of the tabs) and drag down or just drag and drop into the 2nd screen if you have a dual monitor. Done, your resize button will start working again!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

- Open MATE Tweak from the start menu
- Go to Windows
- Under Window manager choose "Compiz (Advanced GPU accelerated desktop effects)"
- This resets the "Window control placement" to Left, so to change that back to Right, you can do so in that same settings window under "Appearance"